# How to use css with php in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm using a wordpress theme options panel similar with propanel I can change the body background with the following code using colorpicker:

```
<?php
$bodybg = get_option('test_bodycolor');
     echo '<body style="background-color:'.$bodybg.'">';
?>
```

The code above is working fine but I dont know how to change a hover links via colorpicker
I made something similar with this code below before  tag to change the paginagion background color:

```
<?php
$linkcolor = get_option('test_pgn');
?>
<style type="text/css">
.pagination a:hover{
    background: <?php echo $linkcolor; ?>;
}
.pagination .current{
    background: <?php echo $linkcolor; ?>;
}
</style>
```

But it doesnt work where I am wrong please can you help me?

Comment: Define "but it doesn't work", what is printed out?

Comment: the syntax looks OK, could you `var_dump($linkcolor);` ?

Comment: So there works only body background I can change the color using colorpicker from theme settings page but the second code for pagination hover wich I gave still in default color ,I change from with colorpicker from red to yellow but it allways stays as red I couldn't understant why do you have another Idea to do that?another way?Thankyou,what you mean with var_dump($linkcolor);?

Comment: `var_dump` will show info about the var. just add this in the line after `$linkcolor`, `var_dump($linkcolor)`, and the paste the result of that in the question.


You do know that you are using the same color for both CSS classes, right?

Comment: that gave me an error like this Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in no I'm using different classes,body you see in my first post I added as a tag <body> with echo but pagination has another class and the option name is mtn_pgn in theme settings where appears the colorpicker box and please sorry for my bad english.In this moment I was looking this article http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ but this doesnt work too.I want to make my wordpress theme configurable by theme settings page for all,links color,pagination color etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks to all for the responses I just found the solution I used this tutorial here http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ when I remove the background colors from style.css and add to custom-style.php it works perfect Now i can change the site colors using my theme settings page but I have a new Problem because when I reset options theme doesn't have colors Is there any way to add a default color to colortpicker?
Here an example of my code

```
$options[] = array( "name" => __('Links Color','framework_localize'),
            "desc" => __('Here you can select the color of your site links.','framework_localize'),
            "id" => $shortname."_lnk",
            "std" => "",
            "type" => "color");
```

Can I add a default color to this code? thanks